# How to check whether the user uploaded a file in PHP?

Tags: php

I do some form validation to ensure that the file a user uploaded is of the right type. But the upload is optional, so I want to skip the validation if he didn't upload anything and submitted the rest of the form. How can I check whether he uploaded something or not? Will `$_FILES['myflie']['size'] <=0` work?

Comment: if(isset($_FILES['name_of_your_files_array'])){} seemed to not work for me.
Also didn't work with if (!empty($_FILES['name_of_your_files_array']))).
I did a var_dump($_FILES) to see what the array $_FILES contains. It had each field an empty string '' (name of the file was '', tmp-name was '', extension was '', etc)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You can use [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php):

```
if(!file_exists($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo 'No upload';
}
```

From the docs:

> Returns TRUE if the file named by
>   filename was uploaded via HTTP POST.
>   This is useful to help ensure that a
>   malicious user hasn't tried to trick
>   the script into working on files upon
>   which it should not be working--for
>   instance, /etc/passwd.
>
> This sort of check is especially
>   important if there is any chance that
>   anything done with uploaded files
>   could reveal their contents to the
>   user, or even to other users on the
>   same system.

EDIT: I'm using this in my FileUpload class, in case it helps:

```
public function fileUploaded()
{
    if(empty($_FILES)) {
        return false;       
    } 
    $this->file = $_FILES[$this->formField];
    if(!file_exists($this->file['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($this->file['tmp_name'])){
        $this->errors['FileNotExists'] = true;
        return false;
    }   
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Actually it works, i had a bug earlier in my code which messed it a bit earlier

Comment: Note that if you're using array e.g. `name=files[]` this causes an error `file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given` you'll have to go deeper to see if `$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0]` is empty/uploaded.

Comment: @karim79, Btw what's the point of the extra `file_exists` check? If `is_uploaded_file()` returns `true`, then surely it's true that the file exists isn't it?

Comment: I would add a previous check:  "if(isset $_FILES['myfile'] ... " to supress warnings

Answer (score 12):

This code worked for me. I am using multiple file uploads so I needed to check whether there has been any upload.

HTML part:

```
<input name="files[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

PHP part:

```
if(isset($_FILES['files']) ){  


foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){

      if(!empty($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key])){

    //  things you want to do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

@karim79 has the right answer, but I had to rewrite his example to suit my purposes.  His example assumes that the name of the submitted field is known and can be hard coded in.  I took that a step further and made a function that will tell me if any files were uploaded without having to know the name of the upload field.

```
/**
 * Tests all upload fields to determine whether any files were submitted.
 * 
 * @return boolean
 */
function files_uploaded() {

    // bail if there were no upload forms
   if(empty($_FILES))
        return false;

    // check for uploaded files
    $files = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
    foreach( $files as $field_title => $temp_name ){
        if( !empty($temp_name) && is_uploaded_file( $temp_name )){
            // found one!
            return true;
        }
    }   
    // return false if no files were found
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input name="my_files[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>


<?php

 if (isset($_FILES['my_files']))
  {
    $myFile = $_FILES['my_files'];
    $fileCount = count($myFile["name"]);


        for ($i = 0; $i <$fileCount; $i++)
         {
           $error = $myFile["error"][$i]; 

            if ($error == '4')  // error 4 is for "no file selected"
             {
               echo "no file selected";
             }
            else
             {

               $name =  $myFile["name"][$i];
               echo $name; 
               echo "<br>"; 
               $temporary_file = $myFile["tmp_name"][$i];
               echo $temporary_file;
               echo "<br>";
               $type = $myFile["type"][$i];
               echo $type;
               echo "<br>";
               $size = $myFile["size"][$i];
               echo $size;
               echo "<br>";



               $target_path = "uploads/$name";   //first make a folder named "uploads" where you will upload files


                 if(move_uploaded_file($temporary_file,$target_path))
                  {
                   echo " uploaded";
                   echo "<br>";
                   echo "<br>";
                  }
                   else
                  {
                   echo "no upload ";
                  }




              }
        }  
}
        ?>


</body>
</html>
```

But be alert. User can upload any type of file and also can hack your server or system by uploading a malicious or php file. In this script there should be some validations. Thank you.

Comment: This one saved my life :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `$_FILES[$form_name]['error']`. It returns `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` if no file was uploaded. Full list: [PHP: Error Messages Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

```
function isUploadOkay($form_name, &$error_message) {
    if (!isset($_FILES[$form_name])) {
        $error_message = "No file upload with name '$form_name' in form.";
        return false;
    }
    $error = $_FILES[$form_name]['error'];

    // List at: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
    if ($error != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        switch ($error) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                $error_message = 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.';
                break;

            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                $error_message = 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.';
                break;

            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                $error_message = 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.';
                break;

            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                $error_message = 'No file was uploaded.';
                break;

            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
                $error_message = 'Missing a temporary folder.';
                break;

            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
                $error_message = 'Failed to write file to disk.';
                break;

            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
                $error_message = 'A PHP extension interrupted the upload.';
                break;

            default:
                $error_message = 'Unknown error';
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    $error_message = null;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`is_uploaded_file()` is great to use, specially for checking whether it is an uploaded file or a local file (for security purposes).

However, if you want to check whether the user uploaded a file, 
use `$_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK`.

See the PHP manual on [file upload error messages](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). If you just want to check for no file, use `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code and think you should try this:

```
if(!file_exists($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'])) 
    {
        echo 'No upload';
    }   
    else
        echo 'upload';
```

Answer (score 1):

In general when the user upload the file, the PHP server doen't catch any exception mistake or errors, it means that the file is uploaded successfully.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php#109648

```php
if ( boolval( $_FILES['image']['error'] === 0 ) ) {
    // ...
}
```