# im trying to add an if else statement for when the form is posted and wether or not the user include files or not?

Tags: php, html, if-statement, isset

how would I do an if / else statement for such? the user has the option of adding images or not. if the add images, i want the if to run and if they dont I want the else to run because depending on whether or not the add an image they will have two different end.

```
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) { 

if (isset($_POST['name'])){  }else{  }

if (isset($_POST['state'])){  }else{  }

if (isset($_FILES['images']['name'])) { echo 'images'; exit;} else {echo 'no images'; exit;}


} #end main form submitted
```

if (isset($_FILES['images']['name'])) dosnt work because as of now even when no images are submitted it still says images submitted.

the html file fields are:

```
<form>
<input type='file' name='images[]' id=''>
<input type='file' name='images[]' id=''>
<input type='file' name='images[]' id=''>
<input type = "submit">    
</form>
```

Comment: please post the full PHP code. It is hard to understand your problem with this snippet.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946418/how-to-check-if-user-uploaded-a-file-in-php)

Comment: @keezy see my answer below i hope its work for you

Comment: @Samad I dont understand how I could use that to do what im tryng to do. when I add this to my code  i get:                                           0 in       C:\xampp\htdocs\bx\modules\step_2.php on   line 84

Comment: @Keezy its working code and i don't know why this code is problem there. how can i send you a file

Comment: @Keezy This code is basically belong to two files one for html.php and second for submit.php see my update answer

Comment: @Samad sorry it does work, I was being slow. after I got some sleep and looked at it again i figured it out. thanks buddy =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try this

> Submit.php

```
<pre>
<?php 
// those index are empty the array filter remove this 

echo "without filter"."<br>";
print_r($_FILES['images']['name']);

echo "filter"."<br>";
$usersFileUpload = array_filter($_FILES['images']['name']);
print_r($usersFileUpload);

$usersFileUploadCount = count($usersFileUpload);

for($i=0;$i<=$usersFileUploadCount;$i++){
    echo $usersFileUpload[$i]."<br>";

    // insert Table     
}
?>
```

> HtmlForm.php

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="images">
<input type='file' name='images[]' id=''><br />
<input type='file' name='images[]' id=''><br />
<input type='file' name='images[]' id=''>
<input name="" type="submit" />
</form>
```

See the image for verification 1

[image]

See the image for verification 2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

im not sure i understand, i think you are trying to do this.

```
if (isset($_FILES['name']) && isset($_FILES['images']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking to see if **$_FILES['images']['error'][$x]** is equal to 4. If I recall correctly, that's indicative of an error with the upload.

Obviously, do that for each iteration of your images uploader, so essentially replace $x with the key for the uploader array.

Remember, an empty array is still a set array.

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php   <-- Manuals. Handy!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($_FILES['your-name-file']['error'] == 4) {
            //process your error
    }
```

It's work for me!