# Why is this error message printing every time form is saved?

Tags: php, forms

```
<?php 
if(isset($_FILES['menubg'])){
    $errors= array();
    $targetDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/user/usermenu_background/'.($_SESSION['user_id']).'';

    // Create target dir
    if (!file_exists($targetDir)) {
        @mkdir($targetDir);
    }
        $file_name = 'menubg.jpg';
//      $file_name = $_FILES['menubg']['name'];
        $file_size =$_FILES['menubg']['size'];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['menubg']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type=$_FILES['menubg']['type'];   
        $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['menubg']['name'])));
        $extensions = array('jpg');         
        if(in_array($file_ext, $extensions) === false){
            $errors[]='extension not allowed, please choose a JPG file.'; 
        }
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be under 2 MB';
        }               
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,'user/usermenu_background/'.($_SESSION['user_id']).'/'.$file_name);
            echo "No errors ";
        } else {
            print_r($errors);
        }
}
?>
```

For some reason every time I save my form I get an error message (
Array ( [0] => extension not allowed, please choose a JPG file. )) that shouldn't be printing unless a file is being uploaded.

When you upload a file it is supposed to check to make sure you are uploading a .jpg file.  It is trapped in: `if(isset($_FILES['menubg'])){}`.  On my form people aren't always going to be uploading a file, and it shouldn't tell me that a blank file has an unallowed extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`is_uploaded_file`](http://www.php.net/is_uploaded_file) method rather than `isset`.

See the answer here: [How to check whether the user uploaded a file in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946418/how-to-check-if-user-uploaded-a-file-in-php)

Comment: I changed the first line to if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['menubg']['tmp_name'])){ and that fixed the problem I wrote about, however I also no longer get an error message if I upload a file with the wrong extension!

Comment: @JamesLyngaas Can you still upload a file with the .jpg extension?

Comment: Yes, that works.  But if I choose a png file it uploads it and names it menubg.jpg.