# PHP move_uploaded_file() Not Working but Also No Errors

Tags: php, apache

This was working perfectly fine when all of the sudden it has just stopped. I don't remember changing anything in this part of my script so it's super weird.

```
$target_dir = "./files/tickets/" . $_SESSION['username'] . "/" . $ticketNumber['ticket_number'];

foreach ($_FILES['ticketFiles']['error'] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['ticketFiles']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $name = basename($_FILES['ticketFiles']['name'][$key]);

        if (!is_dir($target_dir)) {
            mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true);
        }

        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$target_dir/$name")) {
            //move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$target_dir/$name");
            $_SESSION['message'] .= "File " . $name . " have been successfully uploaded.<br>";
        } else {
            $_SESSION['message'] .= "There was an error uploading file " . $name . ". Try again please.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The directory is created but no files show up. The "successfully uploaded" message also displays.

Comment: Hard to tell, but my guess is special characters in `$name`, like leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: Aside: you should add [more validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/946432/1022914).